# NodeJS: Is it possible to pass modules to an isolate in isolated-vm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, isolate

I am trying to execute a script code inside [isolated-vm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isolated-vm)'s isolate. Script code needs some third party packages as dependencies like lodash, node-xlsx, etc.,. Is it possible to pass the dependent modules to an isolate?

Getting the following error while trying to pass module to an isolate:
TypeError: [object Module] could not be cloned.

Code:

```
import ivm from 'isolated-vm'
import _ from 'lodash-es'

(async function() {
        try{
                let code = `
                        async function setup() {
                                log('setup called!!');
                                log('config -> ', config);
                        }
                        setup();
                `;
                const isolate = new ivm.Isolate({ memoryLimit: 128 })
                const context = isolate.createContextSync()

                const jail = context.global
                jail.setSync('global', jail.derefInto());

                const config = {
                        id: 1234,
                        name: 'test'
                }
                jail.setSync('config', new ivm.ExternalCopy(config).copyInto());

                jail.setSync('libraries', new ivm.ExternalCopy(_).copyInto());

                jail.setSync('log', function(...args) {
                        console.log(...args);
                })

                const hostile = isolate.compileScriptSync(code)
                hostile.run(context).catch(err => console.error(err));

                        
        } catch(e) {
                console.log('err->', e)
        }
        
}) ()
```

Expected: Need to access libraries (lodash module) inside setup() function